# TcpListener Client stays connected sending multiple messages but server only receives or processes the first message

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcplistener

I am setting up a server to read some network clients using TcpListener. The Client sends some data I verify that data and send a response to that data, the client stays connected and sends a second response and I verify that data and send a response back, its like logging in to the server twice. The first login get sent back to the client just fine but the second time the client responds the server does not show that it received anymore data from the client.

I have tested it by setting up a dummy client (the real client is Cell phone based ODB2). With the dummy client set up I did verify that the first handshake happens but the when the client sends the second set of text it does not show up on the server.

```
class Program
{
    static private TcpListener listener = null;
    static private TcpClient client = null;
    static private NetworkStream stream = null;
    static private int iCount = 0;
    static Int32 port = 8090;
    static IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.17");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, client);
            }
            catch (IOException ioex)
            {
                RestartStream();
            }
        }
    }
        private static void ThreadProc(object obj)
        {

        var client = (TcpClient)obj;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        stream = client.GetStream();
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead).Replace("-", "");
            byte[] sendBytes;
            if (returndata.ToLower().StartsWith("7e") && returndata.ToLower().EndsWith("7e"))
            {
             //… do stuff with the data and send it back to the client 
             sendBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(login1);
             stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
             stream.Flush();
                              }
                              else
                {
                    SaveStream(returndata);
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Test  Client Code:

```
 //---data to send to the server---
        string textToSend = "7E010000360141850000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035303030303038003131313131313131313131313131313131F67E";

        //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

        //---send the text---
        Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        //---read back the text---
        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));

        string Text2 = "7E0100003601418535303030303038003131313131313131313131313131313131F67E";
        Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + Text2);
        byte[] bytesToSend2 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Text2);
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend2, 0, bytesToSend2.Length);
        client.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

What I need to happen is my understanding is the client stays connected the whole time and send data over and over, my system seems to accept it once and then stops receiving it, I need it to continue to receive the client data and process it.

Comment: Step through the server code with the debugger, and watch what happens in ThreadProc after it processes the first message.

Comment: nothing happens I already tried that … it never processes

Comment: This is a debugging problem

Comment: TheGeneral please explain, even if the debug did not work the console.writeline should show the data. Correct?

Comment: So, what happens in the ThreadProc function after it finishes processing the first message?

Comment: it waits, I can start a second client connection and that processes the same way. I tried starting 6 at once to see if it effects it and it does not. I added threadID to make sure they are on different threads and they are. Its odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, there should be a second while loop in side the thread.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        var clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        listener.Start();
        var counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            clientSocket = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            var client = new ConnectedDevice();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, counter.ToString(), sqlConnString);
        }
    }
```

ConnectedDevice class:

```
class ConnectedDevice
{
    private TcpClient _clientSocket;
    private string _clientNumber;
    private string _sqlConnString;

    public void startClient(TcpClient clientSocket, string clientNumber, string sqlConnString)
    {
        _clientSocket = clientSocket;
        _clientNumber = clientNumber;
        _sqlConnString = sqlConnString;

        var ctThread = new Thread(ProcessClient);
        ctThread.Start();
    }
    private void ProcessClient()
    {
        while (_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                var networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
                int i;
                while ((i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i).Replace("-", "");
                    byte[] sendBytes;
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    string sLogin1 = "7E81000013014185000008000000000054523230313731303138303930303137497E";
                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sLogin1);
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```